# $\sigma$-additivity of the standard part of an internal finitely additive measure on an internal algebra

Tags: measure-theory, nonstandard-analysis

Let $V({}^\ast{X})$ be an enlargement of ${}^{\ast}{V(X)}$ and $C$ be a fixed internal set in $V({}^\ast{X})$. $\{A_k\}_{k \in \Bbb N}$ is strictly increasing sequence of internal subsets of $C$. It is known that $\bigcup_{k \in \Bbb N} A_k$ must be external by countable saturation property.

But why this implies that the standard part of an internal finitely additive measure on an internal algebra is alway $\sigma$-additive?

Answer (score 2):

The issue here seems to be the definition of countable additivity when the measure is defined on an algebra that isn't necessarily a $\sigma$-algebra. The relevant definition here is... (See, for example, *Probability: Theory and Examples* by Rick Durrett.)

A measure $\mu$ on an algebra $\mathcal{A}$ is countably additive if, for every countable sequence of disjoint sets $\{A_k\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ from $\mathcal{A}$, *whose union is also in $\mathcal{A}$*, 
$$\mu\left(\bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{N}}A_k\right)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \mu(A_k).$$

Now, the fact that a countable union of strictly increasing internal sets is external implies that if $\{A_k\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of disjoint internal subsets of $C$ *whose union is also internal*, then only finitely many of the $A_k$s are non-empty. So countable additivity follows from finite additivity.